# Customize Admin Sidebar Menu Items?

Tags: templating, control-panel

Looking for a way to show Channel entries directly on the sidebar for content editors. So if someone has access to:

**DEFAULT STRUCTURE of Sidebar Menu**

- Entries ->

  - CHANNELS ->

    - News

      - News Item 1
      - News Item 2
      - News Item 3

**PREFERRED STRUCTURE of Sidebar Menu**

- News

  - News Item 1
  - News Item 2

In other words, Content Editors don't need to see "Entries" and then "CHANNELS" to get to their section they update. When someone has permissions for a specific Section or Channel, it should be neatly accessible on the left side.

In Craft, what is the correct approach to make this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Craft does not offer this functionality natively. Luckily there's a few plugins out there that will help your users navigate around a bit easier:

In the CP Nav
https://github.com/engram-design/CPNav (This should accomplish your need)
https://github.com/picdorsey/craft-sidebarenhancer

In the Entries index
https://github.com/james1238/EntryTypeSources
https://github.com/engram-design/ExpandedSingles

Comment: Thanks Chase, I'll take a look at those plugins. May need to fork one and add capabilities to include some child elements/menus.